# Добавление условия в DetailView django

Tags: python, django, ооп

Есть следующий класс DetailView в views:

```
class Watches_card(DetailView):
    model = Watches_db
    context_object_name = 'watches_model_info'
    template_name = 'watches/watches_card_published.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'url_watches_model'
    slug_field = 'url_watches_model'
```

models.py:

```
class Watches_db(models.Model):
    url_watches_model = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True,db_index=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('watches_info/<slug:url_watches_model>/', Watches_card.as_view(), name='watches_card')]
```

Есть 2 шаблона (temlates):

1. watches/watches_card_published.html
2. watches/watches_card_not_published.html

Вопрос заклюается в том, как добавить условие в views что бы если is_published (в модели) был True, открывался шаблон watches/watches_card_published.html, если False - watches/watches_card_not_published.html

Мой вариант решения который не дал результата:

```
class Watches_card(DetailView):
    model = Watches_db
    context_object_name = 'watches_model_info'
    if Watches_db.is_published == True:
        template_name = 'watches/watches_card_published.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'watches/watches_card_not_published.html'
    slug_url_kwarg = 'url_watches_model'
    slug_field = 'url_watches_model'
```

Comment: перехватить то место, где рендерится шаблон и там вставлять проверку

Comment: Я просто не понимаю в какую переменную DetailView хранит запись из бд что бы его можно было отфильтровать по атрибуту is_published для проверки

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение: внутри класса `Watches_card` добавил:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    filtered_data = Watches_db.objects.filter(url_watches_model=self.kwargs['url_watches_model'])
    if filtered_data[0].is_published == True:
        self.template_name = 'watches/watches_card_published.html'
    else:
        self.template_name = 'watches/watches_card_not_published.html'
```